# How to change TextView's text on change of EditText's text?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I have an `EditText` box where the user can enter input. I need to display the input text in a `TextView` (which is placed below the EditText) while the user inputting the text.

**Example:**

If the user is entering any characters in EditText box, I need to display the same characters in TextView. In the same way, If the user deletes any character from EditText, I need to remove the same character from TextView. (Ultimately, I want to change TextView's text on change of EditText's text). I hope my requirement is clear now. How can I achieve this? Please guide me.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.andreabaccega.com/blog/2010/10/09/onchange-event-on-edittext-in-android/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add TextWatcher to your Edittext. in `afterTextChanged()` do your operation. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

```
TextWatcher inputTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
                textview.setText(s.toString());
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }
};

editText.addTextChangedListener(inputTextWatcher);
```

Answer (score 5):

You should overwrite this method :

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(editText.getText().length() >= 0) {
            textView.setText(editText.getText().toString())
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: experts same way i would like to populate textview details from database against edittext  entry. example my table details column1 Alex,  column2 12.  While i enter edittext value 12 than textview should show Alex without any button click like keyboard entry detection.

Answer (score 4):

```
edtText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (!edtText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")){

                    // here textview.setText(edtText.getText());

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) to the `EditText` by using `addTextChangedListener()` function. In `TextWatcher` you'll need to write transformation / validation logic inside one of 3 functions `afterTextChanged()`, `beforeTextChanged()`, `onTextChanged()` depending on when you want to perform those actions.

Using Kotlin you would do something like that:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(object : android.text.TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            s?.let { textView.text = s.toString() }
        }
    })
```